# Google Drive API V3 export_media missing Content-Length and Content-Range

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Driver API python library to download file as CSV format.

```
google_drive_service = get_service()
mimeType = 'text/csv'
request = google_drive_service.files().export_media(fileId='abc', mimeType=mimeType)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while not done:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
fh.seek(0)
content = fh.getvalue()
```

Since it is a big tab, the downloading process breaks down by chunks. It keeps printing out "Downloading 0%". While the code is checking the download process, i looped through the library code. The reason why it show "Downloading 0%" all the time is because the http response does not have "content-range" and "content-length" headers, which cause the process check issue.

If you are interested in replicating this process. Create a spreadsheet and fill the cell values for columns 'A:E' and rows '1:10000'. Let me know if anyone had the same issue or have a clue about why this is happening. Here is the Gdrive code: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L664-L691

Answer (score 0):

The http response will only have content-range headers if the http request asked for them. According to https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads, partial downloads are not supported for exports, only for downloads.

A few things you could try:-
 1. In the v2 API, a file resource has an array of  static exportLinks. You could try doing a partial download on the appropriate link. Instead of the python library, You would need to do your own REST get using the same credential.
 1. You could look at using the "publish" feature of Google Spreadsheets to create a downloadable link to the CSV.